# Liferay changes made to source code through ext plugin are not taking place

Tags: java, ldap, liferay, liferay-6

I needed to override `portalLDAPImporterImpl.java` `addUser()` method to perform some action after a user is imported from LDAP and added to Liferay. I followed these steps (Eclipse Environment):

1. Created Ext plugin project name customLdap;
2. In **docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src** I created a package name **com.liferay.portal.security.ldap**
3. There I create my **CustomPortalLDAPImporterImpl.java** class extending **portalLDAPImporterImpl.java** and override the method **addUser**

Code extract:

```
    @Override

    protected User addUser(long companyId, LDAPUser ldapUser, String password)
        throws Exception {

    if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        _log.debug("Adding user " + ldapUser.getEmailAddress());
    }

    boolean autoPassword = ldapUser.isAutoPassword();

    if (!PropsValues.LDAP_IMPORT_USER_PASSWORD_ENABLED) {
        autoPassword = PropsValues.LDAP_IMPORT_USER_PASSWORD_AUTOGENERATED
                && !PropsValues.AUTH_PIPELINE_ENABLE_LIFERAY_CHECK;

        if (!autoPassword) {
            String defaultPassword = PropsValues.LDAP_IMPORT_USER_PASSWORD_DEFAULT;

            if (StringUtil.equalsIgnoreCase(defaultPassword,
                    _USER_PASSWORD_SCREEN_NAME)) {

                defaultPassword = ldapUser.getScreenName();
            }

            password = defaultPassword;
        }
    }

    Calendar birthdayCal = CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar();

    birthdayCal.setTime(ldapUser.getBirthday());

    int birthdayMonth = birthdayCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int birthdayDay = birthdayCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int birthdayYear = birthdayCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(ldapUser.getCreatorUserId(),
            companyId, autoPassword, password, password,
            ldapUser.isAutoScreenName(), ldapUser.getScreenName(),
            ldapUser.getEmailAddress(), 0, StringPool.BLANK,
            ldapUser.getLocale(), ldapUser.getFirstName(),
            ldapUser.getMiddleName(), ldapUser.getLastName(), 0, 0,
            ldapUser.isMale(), birthdayMonth, birthdayDay, birthdayYear,
            StringPool.BLANK, ldapUser.getGroupIds(),
            ldapUser.getOrganizationIds(), ldapUser.getRoleIds(),
            ldapUser.getUserGroupIds(), ldapUser.isSendEmail(),
            ldapUser.getServiceContext());
    _log.info("-----------------------------------------User||||Added----------------------------------------");

    if (ldapUser.isUpdatePortrait()) {
        byte[] portraitBytes = ldapUser.getPortraitBytes();

        if (ArrayUtil.isNotEmpty(portraitBytes)) {
            user = UserLocalServiceUtil.updatePortrait(user.getUserId(),
                    portraitBytes);
        }
    }

    return user;
}
```

4. Created folder name **META-INF** in **docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src**
5. In **META-INF** created a file named ext-spring.xml with the following code:

[image]

6. build and published my plugin
7. copied the customLdap-ext.war file from dist folder and pasted it in my Tomcat deploy folder
8. started my server the old configuration are loaded no log is printed while a new user is imported from ldap

Where am I going wrong in doing this?

Note: I am using liferay 6.2.0.1 CE-GA6

Comment: 6.2.0.1 CE-GA6? Where did you get that - from original sources it doesn't exist. 6.2.5 would be the version matching "GA6", 6.2.0 is GA1. I've never heard of 6.2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also overriden `PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java`. You don't have to define ext-spring.xml. Just take the original class, copy it to `docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src` in package `com.liferay.portal.security.ldap` and change it. Do not create `CustomPortalLDAPImporterImpl.java`

Comment: did exactly what you said but still no changes reflected

Comment: And after ext deployment have you restarted server? Also undeploy and remove the leftovers of your old ext.

Comment: i also did that

Comment: Maybe message(`_log.info`) isn't printed because default log level on `com.liferay.portal.security.ldap ` is `ERROR`, you have to go to control panel -> server administration -> log levels and change the logging level of this package to info. Have you tried to debug this class with eclipse?

Comment: thanks a lot for the help mate followed your steps and it worked. The last problem was because I was unable to un-deploy my old ext plugin properly, I had to delete the files and jar one by one. Now my custom changes are reflected but still, my logs are not printing

Answer (score 0):

Something in your description doesn't sound right - specifically the combination of an ext-plugin and

> 6. build and pusblished my plugin
> 7. copied the customLdap-ext.war file from dist folder and pasted it in my tomcat delpoy folder

While this is [documented as the steps to deploy in production](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/advanced-customization-with-ext-plugins#method-1-redeploying-liferays-web-application), you'll at least need to restart Liferay (ext is not hot-deployable).

Also, validate that the WAR file *doesn't* end up as a separate webapplication in tomcat. Instead it will be woven into Liferay, aka the ROOT web application. This is another thing that you can/should validate. And observe the documented steps for redeployment (different from first deployment), where you basically need to reinstall Liferay from scratch and your ext plugins.

I haven't validated if you can go without ext here, the documented steps are a prime reason to try to go without ext whenever possible.

If you follow Klimiuk's advice in the other answer to this question, note that you're depending on classloader order in that case: Some JVMs/appservers will pick up your implementation first, while others pick up the original one first. It's typically reproducible - e.g. if it works once, it'll always work. At least until an update to your environment changes the behavior any you suddenly wonder why your modification doesn't work any more (if you're lucky to find out quickly).